# std::rotate for a right rotation gives me a heapoverflow

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to solve [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/) leetcode question where i'm supposed to perform a right rotation on a vector by k positions. Since std::rotate does a left rotation I tried using reverse iterators to accomplish the opposite result:

```
    void rotate(vector<int>& nums, int k) 
    {
        std::rotate(nums.rbegin(), nums.rbegin() + k, nums.rend());
    }
```

Now this works for the first 2 test cases, but when I submit it, I get a runtime error saying i've got a heapoverflow, here's the error:

```
=21==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000034c at pc 0x000000369815 bp 0x7fff32cde700 sp 0x7fff32cde6f8
READ of size 4 at 0x60200000034c thread T0
    #3 0x7f55da0cc082  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
0x60200000034c is located 4 bytes to the left of 4-byte region [0x602000000350,0x602000000354)
```

What gives? Is there a problem with my code? From what i've tested it seems fine. If this is a problem with the leetcode platform itself, i'll delete this question.

Comment: `0 <= k <= 105` -- I would believe that the trick is that you don't actually rotate this many times.  If you have a vector of 10 elements, if `k` is 10, 20, 30, etc., then the vector winds up in its original state (no actual rotation is done).  In other words, modulus should be used.

Comment: I had to go to the Leetcode site to see the constraints.  You should post those constraints here.  Obviously the code will not work if the vector has `n` elements and `k >= n`, all due to `nums.rbegin() + k` being an invalid iterator.  Also, the `k` upper limit is actually 10^5 and not 105, as my first comment stated.  So you can imagine if `n` is 2, and k is 100000 how that blows up everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will fail if the number of positions to rotate exceeds the size of the vector.

`std::rotate(nums.rbegin(), nums.rbegin() + k, nums.rend());`

If `k >= nums.size()`, then `nums.rbegin() + k` will be an invalid iterator, thus the runtime error you're seeing.

The fix is to rotate a modulus of `k` with the size of the vector, and not actually `k` places.

`std::rotate(nums.rbegin(), nums.rbegin() + k % nums.size(), nums.rend());`

For example, if `nums.size()` is 10, and `k` is 20, 30, 40, the modulus will yield 0, thus no actual rotation is done. On the other hand, if `k` is 21, 22, etc., then an actual rotation of 1, 2, etc. will be done.